# How to add button's id into the td tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button.
So what I am trying to do is adding the button's id into the  tag as a value.

```js
function addRow() {
  document.querySelector("#content").insertAdjacentHTML(
    "afterbegin",
    `<tr>
        <td>id</td>
      </tr>`
  );
}
```

```html
<div id="1/8/2021" type="button" onclick="addRow()" style="width: 80px; height: 60px;"><span class="month">AUGUST</span>1</div>
```

So for example, in this case instead of id, it should be written "1/8/2021".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the button as a parameter and get its id:

```html
<div id="1/8/2021" type="button" onclick="addRow(this)" style="width: 80px; height: 60px;"><span class="month">AUGUST</span>1</div>
```

```js
function addRow(btn) {
  document.querySelector("#content").insertAdjacentHTML(
    "afterbegin",
    `<tr>
    <td>${btn.id}</td>
  </tr>`
  );
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Ill accept your answer but I need to wait a little bit